# In Couchbase or N1QL how can I check if the values in an array match

Tags: view, couchbase, sql++

In a couchbase I have the following document structure...

```
{
    name: "bob",
    permissions: [
        2,
        4,
        6
    ]
}
```

I need to be able to create a view, or N1QL query which will check if the permissions for "bob" are contained within a given array.

e.g  I have an array with contents

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I need the "bob" document to be returned because my array contains 2,4,6 and so does "bob"

If my array contained 1,3,4,5,6 "bob" should **not** be selected because my array does not contain "2"

Essentially I want to match any documents whose permission entries are all contained in my array.

The solution can either a view or an N1QL query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using N1QL, you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM my_bucket WHERE EVERY p IN permissions SATISFIES p IN [ 1,2,3,4,5,6 ] END;
```